# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request - SOAP message based on WS Security UsernameToken Profile 1.1, WS-I Basic Profile 1.1

Tags: security, authentication, soap, token

At first, I write the soap envelope, which contains the original XML file. The soap envelope is made with the following code:

```pascal
procedure MakeSoapEnvelope(FileNameIn: AnsiString);
Const
  SpCon = 0;
  MINPERDAY = 1440;
  SourceFile = 'XMLFILE';
  TargetFile = 'SOAPENVELOP';
Var
  AStr, Bapi_Versie_Pen_Soap, StrType: AnsiString;
  uNow: _SystemTime;
  dtNow: TDateTime;
  sNow: String;
  FSource, FDest : System.Text;

  function FillTag(TagIn, FillPart:AnsiString) : AnsiString;
  var
    HTr: Integer;
  begin
    Result := NulStr;
    for HTr := 1 to Length(TagIn) do
    begin
      if (HTr = Length(TagIn)) then //direct voor laatste positie invoegen
        Result := Result + Spatie + FillPart;
      Result := Result + TagIn[HTr];
    end;
  end; {func FillTag}

  procedure FDestAdd(SpIn : Integer; TagIn, VeldIn, FillIn : AnsiString);
  begin
    if (FillIn = NulStr) then
    begin
      WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(SpIn * AuditSpatieMarge), TagIn, VeldIn, EndTag(TagIn));
    end else
    begin
      Write(FDest, Spatie:(SpIn * AuditSpatieMarge));
      Write(FDest, FillTag(TagIn, FillIn));
      Write(FDest, VeldIn);
      Write(FDest, EndTag(TagIn));
      WriteLn(FDest, NulStr);
    end;
  end; {proc FDestAdd}

  function GenerateTimestampId : AnsiString;
  var
    IntUit : Integer;
  begin
    IntUit := 1 + Random(100);
    Result := '"_' + ItoSNulZonderPunten(IntUit) + '"';
  end; {func GenerateTimestampId}

  function MaakGUID : AnsiString;
  var
    Uid: TGuid;
  begin
    CreateGuid(Uid);
    Result := (GuidToString(Uid));
    //verwijderen accolades
    Result := VerwijderEnkelTeken(Result, '{');
    Result := VerwijderEnkelTeken(Result, '}');
  end; {func MaakGUID}

  function GenerateUserNameTokenId : AnsiString;
  begin
    Result := MaakGUID;
    Result := '"' + Result + '"';
  end; {func GenerateUserNameTokenId}

begin {procedure MakeSoapEnvelope}

  { start reserve file }
  AssignFile(FDest, TargetFile);
  Rewrite(FDest);

  //prepare SoAP-envelope-header
  WinApi.Windows.GetSystemTime(uNow);
  dtNow := SysUtils.SystemTimeToDateTime(uNow);
  sNow := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"', dtNow);

  //write SoAP-envelope-header
  Bapi_Versie_Pen_Soap := Bapi_Versie_PenSoap_UPA_AGH;
  WriteLn(FDest, {Spatie:(0 * AuditSpatieMarge),} Bapi_Versie_Pen_Soap);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(1 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Alg_Soap_Header_Start);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(2 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Security_Start);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(3 * AuditSpatieMarge), FillTag(Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Timestamp, Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Id + GenerateTimestampId));
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(4 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Created, FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"', dtNow), EndTag(Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Created));
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(4 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Expires, FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"', dtNow + 5 /MINPERDAY), EndTag(Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Expires));
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(3 * AuditSpatieMarge), EndTag(Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Timestamp));
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(3 * AuditSpatieMarge), FillTag(Xml_PA_Upa_UsernameToken_Start, Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Id + GenerateUserNameTokenId));
  FDestAdd(4, Xml_PA_Upa_Username, XmlSendDlg.MeUserName.Text, NulStr);
  FDestAdd(4, Xml_PA_Upa_Password, TranslateTo64Base(XmlSendDlg.MePassword.Text), Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Password_Type);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(3 * AuditSpatieMarge), EndTag(Xml_PA_Upa_UsernameToken_Start));
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(2 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_Security_Stop);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(2 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_To);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(2 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_AGH_Action);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(1 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Alg_Soap_Header_Stop);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(1 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Alg_Soap_Body_Start);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(2 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_ZendBerichtAlsZIP_Start);
  FDestAdd(3, Xml_PA_Upa_idLcr, Bepaal_Upa_IdLcr, NulStr);
  FDestAdd(3, Xml_PA_Upa_idBer, XmlSendDlg.OrIdBericht, NulStr);
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(3 * AuditSpatieMarge), Xml_PA_Upa_berichtZIP_Start);

  { open original xml file }
  SourceFile := FileNameIn;
  {$I-}
  AssignFile(FSource, SourceFile);
  Reset(FSource);
  { incorporate original xml file in soapenvelope}
  while not Eof(FSource) do
  begin
    ReadLn(FSource, AStr);
    WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(4 * AuditSpatieMarge), AStr);
  end;
  CloseFile(FSource);

  {add endtag xml file in soapenvelope}
  WriteLn(FDest, 3 * AuditSpatieMarge,     EndTag(Xml_PA_Upa_berichtZIP_Start));
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(2 * AuditSpatieMarge), EndTag(Xml_PA_Upa_ZendBerichtAlsZIP_Start));

  {write end soap-envelope }
  WriteLn(FDest, Spatie:(1 * AuditSpatieMarge), EndTag(Xml_PA_Alg_Soap_Body_Start));
  WriteLn(FDest, {Spatie:(0 * AuditSpatieMarge),} Xml_PA_Alg_Soap_Envelope_Einde);

  CloseFile(FDest);

  { save nieuwe file op in oude file }
  RenameResFile(SourceFile, TargetFile);
  {$I+}
end; { func MakeSoapEnvelope }
```

Please note: I am not sure that `MePassword.Text` converted into Base64 is sufficient for WS Security.

After this, the soap envelope looks like this:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="_83">
        <wsu:Created>2017-11-06T12:29:14Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-11-06T12:34:14Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="C2F32D7E-805F-466C-BD2B-FB0B28C01E24">
        <wsse:Username>MeUsername.Text</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">This line represents the MePassword.Text in 64Base</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    <To soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://localhost:44300/UPAWebService.svc</To>
    <Action soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.pensioenfederatie.nl/uniformePensioenAangifte/2015/05/WS/UPAWebService/ZendBerichtAlsZIP</Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ws:ZendBerichtAlsZIP>
      <ws:idLcr>A95972643</ws:idLcr>
      <ws:idBer>CLIENT-PA-01A-20171106132913</ws:idBer>
      <ws:berichtZIP>This line represents the original xml-file</ws:berichtZIP>
    </ws:ZendBerichtAlsZIP>
```

The soap envelope is sent with this code:

```
procedure Send_HTTP;
var
  XMLFileStream : TFileStream;
begin  {procedure Send_HTTP}
  XMLFileStream := TFileStream.Create(XmlSendDlg.XmlFileIn, fmOpenRead Or fmShareDenyWrite);
  Try
    IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP1.HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth, hoKeepOrigProtocol, hoForceEncodeParams];
    IdHTTP1.IoHandler.Port := Port_HTTPS;
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';
    IdHTTP1.Request.Username := MeUsername.Text;
    IdHTTP1.Request.Password := MePassword.Text;
    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;//True;
    IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := ReadTimeoutConst;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('SOAPAction: "' + MeSoapAction.Text + '"');
    Try
      ReturnStr := IdHTTP1.Post(MeWebSite.Text, XMLFileStream);
    Except
      On E: Exception Do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Fout: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;
    IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
  Finally
    XMLFileStream.Free;
  end;
end; {proc Send_HTTP}
```

Sending the soap envelope results in a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` response. The complete message received is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 12:29:15 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: You are obviously sending something the server does not like. The XML you showed is incomplete. Where is the closing tags for the `Envelope` and `Body` elements? Why are you creating the XML manually instead of using `(T|I)XMLDocument` or other XML engine? Or better, why not use an actual SOAP library that handles all of these details for you?

Comment: Incomplete XML: I just forgot to copy and paste those last lines. They exist in my source code and this works sending most soap envelops, apart form the one that requires ws security.                                         Right now I am changing my code by using XMLDocument. I will comment on that later.                                                                              If better, where should I look for 'an actual SOAP library'?